# Drools Error- ERR 102 Line 9:143 mismatched input '==' in rule

Tags: drools, jbpm

I am trying to configure a Decision table to evaluate certain condition.

Below is the snippet from my decision table.

While doing so I am getting following error

[ERR 102] Line 8:143 mismatched input '==' in rule "Rules_11".

I am not sure about what I am doing wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in line 9
The condition cannot have a variable with a comparison floating there. 
$selectedAttribute.code in line 9 doesn't mean anything, that's not a Conditional element.